# Is there a faster way to export rows in Excel to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

I have 8,500 rows with 36 columns that I need to insert to a SQL Server table, and currently it's taking 9 minutes. I was wondering if there is a faster way to do this. I've read up on bulk inserts but I'm saving that as a last resort.

Currently how I'm doing it, is that I'm using a for each loop and having an if statement to check if each cell is formatted properly (probably a reason why its slow, but I need it there). And I'm concatenating them all to be exported at once.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you are looking for a VBA based solution and not T-SQL? Can you provide sample code that shows the processes you go through in the loop? That would be the first place to pick up efficiency.

Comment: I will after it's done running. I was just thinking if there is a way to just export a csv file to sql just using vba or something that'll be faster.

Comment: Separate the validation from export to sql server. To optimize the network load, you can create stored proc, so only values are passed.

Comment: Not sure how often you have to do this, but if its a 1x or rarely ... right click the database and go to Import, follow the wizard. SSIS is always best if long term.

Answer (score 1):

First, you neeed to install this driver ([Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0]) on your instance of SQl-server

[Download Here - Driver](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

then execute this query on SQL-Sever:

```
  select * 
  into mytable
  from OpenDataSource('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;Database=c\desktop\myExcelfile.xlsm')...[mySheet$]
```

Don't remove this character "$"

Comment: Thomas, maybe the next video that I record for you, could help you: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3p88EQFnMR_SU56SDFBNE1MdEU/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You can drastically improve the performance by working with an array and by using a buffer to build the query.
It should take just a few millisecond to build a query with 10000 rows.
Here is an example:

```
Sub build_query()
  Dim buffer As String, length&, data(), r&, c&

  ' load the data in an array '
  data = Range("A2:C5")

  ' create the string buffer '
  buffer = String$(2048, vbNullChar)

  ' write the header '
  Append buffer, length, "INSERT INTO [MyTable] ('ColA', 'ColB', 'ColB') Values(" & vbCrLf

  ' iterate each cell '
  For r = 1 To UBound(data)
    Append buffer, length, "("
    For c = 1 To UBound(data, 2)
      If c > 1 Then Append buffer, length, ","

      ' convert each type '
      Select Case VarType(data(r, c))
        Case vbDate:
          Append buffer, length, format(data(r, c), "'yyyy-mm-dd HH:nn:ss'")
        Case vbString:
          Append buffer, length, "'" & data(r, c) & "'"
        Case Else:
          Append buffer, length, CStr(data(r, c))
      End Select

    Next
    Append buffer, length, ")," & vbCrLf
  Next

  ' write the footer '
  length = length - 3 ' remove comma '
  Append buffer, length, ");"

  ' display the result '
  Debug.Print Left$(buffer, length)
End Sub

Private Sub Append(buffer$, length&, text$)
  length = length + Len(text)
  If length > Len(buffer) Then
    buffer = buffer & String$(Len(buffer) * (length \ Len(buffer)), vbNullChar)
  End If
  Mid$(buffer, length - Len(text) + 1) = text
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I've  created an Excel Add-In where you can export Excel data to SQL Server. Did a test with 8500 rows and 40 columns and it took 4.5 seconds to insert the rows in Excel to SQL Server.

I sell it as a commerial prodcut, but if it is a time limited job, you can use the full functional trial for free (and if you need, just send me an email and I'll extended the trial for you).

You can download it here http://sqlspreads.com/download-sql-spreads/